# Is there a limit on the amount of JavaScript Files on your head?

Tags: php, html, javascript

I'm asking because every time I use a second javascript my code gets buggy. At first the JS file was one and I was trying to make it work for both the select tags I'm working with. I wasn't able to implement it. Called it quiets and copied it but renamed everything to avoid any conflicts in the name. But my errors keep on happening. Maybe there's something wrong with my code or?

**html Head**

```
<head>
    <title>Packages</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style_p.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../style/add_fields.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../style/addMoreFields.js"></script>

    <h1><img src="../images/Logo.png" alt="Logo"></h1>
</head>
```

**JS 1**

```
var instance = 0;

function moreFields(parentHome, cloneHome) {
    // Check if there isn't more than 3 fields
    if(instance != 3) {
        instance++;
        // Create a child
        var TempClone = document.getElementById(parentHome).cloneNode(true);

        // remove templet clone's id to avoid future confusion
        TempClone.id = "";
        TempClone.style.display = 'block';

        /* Get the cloned templet's
         * Children. Here we will make
         * only the ones who have a name
         * unique.
         */
        var cloneC = TempClone.childNodes;
        for(var i = 0; i < cloneC.length; i++) {
            var ChildName = cloneC[i].name;
            if(ChildName)
                cloneC[i].name = ChildName + instance;
        }

        // Locate clone's home 
        var insertHere = document.getElementById(cloneHome);
        // Place clone in home
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(TempClone,insertHere);
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    moreFields('SnackBox', 'SnackPlate');
}
```

**JS2**

```
var counter = 0;

function addMoreFields(srcHome, cloneHome) {
    // Check if there isn't more than 3 fields
    if(counter != 3) {
        counter++;
        // Create a child
        var template = document.getElementById(srcHome).cloneNode(true);

        // remove templet clone's id to avoid future confusion
        template.id = "";
        template.style.display = 'block';

        /* Get the cloned templet's
         * Children. Here we will make
         * only the ones who have a name
         * unique.
         */
        var copy = template.childNodes;
        for(var i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            var cloneName = copy[i].name;
            if(cloneName)
                copy[i].name = cloneName + counter;
        }

        // Locate clone's home 
        var endLocation = document.getElementById(copyHome);
        // Place clone in home
        endLocation.parentNode.insertBefore(Template,endLocation);
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    addMreFields('SoupBox', 'SoupBowl');
}
```

**html code**

```
        <td><div id="SnackBox" style="display:none">
            <select id="dfood" name="dfood">
                <option>--Select--</option>
                <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survival_mode.dryfood_t", $link);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='{$row['dfood_ID']}'>{$row['dfood_name']}</option>";
                }
                echo "\n";
                ?>
            </select>
            <input name="df_qty" type="text" placeholder="qty" size="1" maxlength="1"/>
            <?php
            if($climate == "warm") {
                echo "\n\t\t\t\t<input type='button' value='-' onclick='if(instance > 1){instance--; this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);}' />";
                echo "\n\t\t\t\t<input type='button' value='+' onclick='moreFields(\"SnackBox\", \"SnackPlate\");' />";
            }
            echo "\n";
            ?>
            </div>
            <span id="SnackPlate"></span>
        </td>

        <td><div id="SoupBox">
            <select id="Soup" name="Soup">
                <option>--Select--</option>
                <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survival_mode.soup_t", $link);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='{$row['soup_ID']}'>{$row['soup_name']}</option>";
                }
                echo "\n";
                ?>
            </select>
            <input name="s_qty" type="text" placeholder="qty" size="1" maxlength="1" />
            <?php
            if($climate == "cold") {
                echo "\n\t\t\t\t<input type='button' value='-' onclick='if(counter > 1){counter--; this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);}' />";
                echo "\n\t\t\t\t<input type='button' value='+' onclick='addMoreFields(\"SoupBox\", \"SoupBowl\");' />";
            }
            echo "\n";
            ?>
            </div>
            <span id="SoupBowl"></span>
        </td>
```

Comment: I see that you define your onload twice!! And in the second one you've a typo too!!

Comment: @Jeanluca: +1, although the exclamation marks make it sound a liiiittle aggressive.

Comment: Could you be a more specific where is the type and where is the double declaration of the onload? It could be helpful on the count of I have tunnel vision at this point.

Comment: sorry for the exclamation marks. Absolutely no intend to be agressive :) (next time I'll omit them).
The typo is in the JS2 onload method, you make a call to addMreFields, which does not exist

Comment: @user2337345: You are assigning to `window.onload` twice (both in the end of the respective file); and the second handler will overwrite the previous one. Instead, use `window.addEventListener("load", function(){…});`

Comment: So should I make one `window.onlaod = function(){ moreFields('...,...');}` and the second one `window.addEventListener("load", function() { addMoreFields('..','..')}`?

Comment: Also, maybe you guys may have an idea why I keep getting an error. Originally I wanted to have just used only one javascript file(the **JS1**) for both those fields. But the same issue I am facing now happened before too. I would use the `window.onload = function(){ moreFields('SnackBox', 'SnackPlate'); moreFeidls('SoupBox', 'SoupBowl');}` Is this the correct interpretation or should I use the `window.addEventListener("load", function() {...}` instead?